# Drupal Display View Rewrite Result text translation

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have few views on drupal for different Article Categories and to make them looks like i need to, i've used rewrite result field. Here is the example of that field:

```
<div class="kl-title">
<div class="kl-date kl-sprite">[created_1]</div>
<h3>[title]</h3>
Posted on <b>[created]</b> in [field_article_category]
</div>
```

But i have no idea how is it better to translate "Posted on" and "in" texts here. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them inside [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function, to make them available for translation.

```
<?php print t("Posted on"); ?> <b>[created]</b> <?php print t("in"); ?> [field_article_category]
```

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't necessary to use t() function but you've lead me to the /admin/config/regional/translate/translate inteface where i've found the full string from **rewrite** **result** **field**